# pdns-recursor incorrect result for dig

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I am a linux newbie and got assigned this task to get the error in our company dns where when we do a dig on localhost, example "dig google.com@localhost" i get an NXDomain status and no answer section (answer:0).

and this is my result from that.....

```
dig @localhost google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.5.0-P2 <<>> @localhost google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

please assist on where the error could be.

Answer (score 0):

and this is my result from that.....

dig @localhost google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.5.0-P2 <<>> @localhost google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

please some1 help.